# Connect to gmail (using imap and javamail) with encrypted password

Tags: email, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to connect to gmail using a simple java program ([like this one](https://harikrishnan83.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/access-gmail-with-imap-using-java-mail-api/)). But my question is:

Is there a way to do this with encrypted password and not the real password, for security reasons of course!! something like how we do in java-Oracle db ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the only authentication mechanism for IMAP is [the `LOGIN` command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.2.3), which takes an unencrypted username and password.  You can add an encryption layer on top of it, either by connecting via IMAPs or starting a TLS layer via the `STARTTLS` command, but it still requires the client to know the cleartext password.

A server can optionally also provide SASL authentication methods invokable via [the `AUTHENTICATE` command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.2.2).  The server advertises which SASL mechanisms it supports in its response to the `CAPABILITY` command.  For instance, if the server includes the capability "`AUTH=PLAIN`", the client can use the `PLAIN` SASL authentication method via the `AUTHENTICATE PLAIN` IMAP command.

Gmail supports only one SASL authentication mechanism, `XOAUTH`:

```
C: 1 capability
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA XLIST CHILDREN XYZZY
      SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH
S: 1 OK Thats all she wrote! dv32if2169247ibb.17
```

`XOAUTH` is a nonstandard SASL authentication mechanism using OAuth.  (The leading 'X' means it's not standardized.)  Google has published [a document defining the `XOAUTH` SASL mechanism](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html).  They've also provided a [google-mail-xoauth-tools package](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode), which includes sample code showing how to use JavaMail with Gmail via `XOAUTH`.

Comment: You still have to write your password in plain text somewhere though - either in the code, or in a properties file.