# javamail - recommended method for authenticating to imap server? (gmail)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

Rather than store my password in the code or config files,  is there an easy way to use an Oauth token instead?   Thought about encrypting it,  but thats like hiding a key under the doormat...

Comment: Easy? No.  Nothing about OAuth is easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to gmail (using imap and javamail) with encryted password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183651/connect-to-gmail-using-imap-and-javamail-with-encryted-password)

Answer (score 0):

That's what [google suggests you do](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview), actually. And... [ahem](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=gmail%20imap%20oauth)...